# (Ubuntu 23.10) Low resolution boot screen then stuck at blinking cursor

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, nouveau

After the uninstallation of nVidia drivers, it's supposed to use the Nouveau driver properly, but instead the boot screen (Ubuntu logo) appears in low resolution and the login screen doesn't appear (stuck at black screen with blinking cursor). I can only use tty1-tty6 terminals there.

Booting into recovery menu using GRUB, typing `exit`, the login screen appears but the screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and in Settings > About OS, the graphics appears as `Software Rendering` when it's supposed to be `NV96`.

Using `lsmod | grep nouveau` returns that the Nouveau drivers are installed however.

How do I get Nouveau working properly again? Installed nVidia drivers and uninstalled back, ran `dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-drivers-nouveau` and `apt-get purge *nvidia*` many times but no luck.

The GPU is GeForce 9400M by the way, and this issue happened after trying to use `nvidia-legacy` packages from `kelebek333` repositories.

Comment: Switching between onboard GPU and the external one solved the problem for a while (onboard is Intel i915), and when switched back to the external (9400 GT), now I can get to the desktop but the screen is stuck at 1024x768, and in About OS, as said the driver became Software Rendering. How can I enable Nouveau drivers now?

Comment: Just put up a spare Radeon HD 4550 and that (AMD RV710 driver) also works, so I suppose nouveau just broke... tried very hard (reinstall Xorg, Wayland, nouveau and such) but still no luck